# xml response from a url

Tags: xml, url, response

I wrote some small codes to read XML from a URL response as below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class example{


    private static String url="http://www.example.com/";




    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {


        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());




}
```

}

the problem lies here: it gives so many errors, for example, it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

or other things , based on the website. i tried but it didnt work for any website i tried so far. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

the URL should point to a document or a file to read it as a stream.
eg URL: http://www.example.com/products/downloads/information.xml

Comment: ooh , so if the page contains HTML, it fails? if so, then how to parse it and then creat its DOM?

Comment: i even tried this as url **http://www.tabnak.ir/sitemap.xml/** but still failed!!!!!